# Preview.app replacement that has rulers

Tags: images

Good example of the Apple minimalism fetish hurting more than helping... I need an  image editor with rulers, but not as full featured as P-Shop.

Curious what other Mac users are using.

Comment: What is ***P-Shop***? I *guess* I know what you might mean, but we do not want to guess to post a possible answer ...

Comment: Welcome to Software Recommendations! We will need much more information to give good recommendations here. Please take a look at [What is required for a question to contain "enough information"?](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/336/185) Then please [edit] your question and see if you can incorporate some of these improvements. Especially missing: What features do you need? Just rulers probably won't be enough. What's your price margin if it comes to paid solutions? And am I guessing right it should run on M (MS Windows, MacOS, Maguro … P-something)?

Answer (score 0):

You may find it difficult to find a program not as full featured as any other. Most publishers are going to put as much into software as they can manage. Each program will have its own idiosyncrasies and learning curve, some more challenging than others.

If you're looking for a free program with rulers, consider [GIMP](https://www.gimp.org/) which is available for the [Mac world](https://www.gimp.org/downloads/) as well as Windows and Linux.

[image: gimp wilber]